# NumPy sum axis for nested arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not getting what I would expect when doing a sum on nested arrays using NumPy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vals = np.array([[[38., 27.], [20., 12.]], [[10., 27.], [10., 30.]], [[13., 16.], [5., 5.]]])
>>> vals.sum(axis=1)
array([[58., 39.],
       [20., 57.],
       [18., 21.]])
```

I would have expected the "axis=1" to have carried all the way through and instead result in the following:

```
array([65., 32.],
      [37., 40.],
      [40,, 29.])
```

But possibly I'm just not thinking through axes properly! In any event, I think my desired result is coherent, so any help you can give in achieving it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your array is (3,2,2).  If you started with a (2,3,4), then the effect of choosing a particular axis would be clearer. That axis disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I think you meant to use axis=2

and that the final row of your expectation is a typo?

```
array([[65., 32.],
       [37., 40.],
       [29., 10.]])
```

#### Remember the axes start at 0, and work outside-to-inside

If you sum along axis = 2, you are summing the *innermost* groups of data, which produces what you want. You may like to think of it like this:

```
np.array([  [ 38 + 27, 20 + 12], 
            [ 10 + 27, 10 + 30], 
            [ 13 + 16,  5 +  5]
         ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a bit more complicated solution which may help you understand how to play with the axis. Here I am using the `transpose` method from numpy to transpose your original array, then I obtain the transpose of your expected result so I use `transpose` once more. The code is the following:

```
np.transpose(vals).sum(axis=0).transpose()
```

The output is, as expected:

```
array([[65., 32.],
       [37., 40.],
       [29., 10.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The axis parameter specifies which axis to perform the sum operation on.
Try this:

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.array([[[38., 27.], [20., 12.]], [[10., 27.], [10., 30.]], [[13., 16.], [5., 5.]]])
result = vals.sum(axis=(1,2))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Axis or axes along which a sum is performed" can be confusing, especially when 2 or more of the dimensions are same, or the array is 2d.

For 1d, it can only have one meaning.  For 3d, where all dimensions differ, the action becomes clearer.  One axis is "removed", the other 2 remain.

```
In [179]: x=np.ones((2,3,4),int)

In [180]: x.sum(axis=0)
Out[180]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 2],    # (3,4) shape
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])

In [181]: x.sum(axis=1)
Out[181]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3],     # (2,4) shape, 3 values are summed
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])

In [182]: x.sum(axis=2)   
Out[182]: 
array([[4, 4, 4],       # (2,3)
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

or keep the summed dimension with:

```
In [183]: x.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True)
Out[183]: 
array([[[4],          # (2,3,1)
        [4],
        [4]],

       [[4],
        [4],
        [4]]])
```

And with a tuple of axes

```
In [185]: x.sum(axis=(0,2), keepdims=True)
Out[185]: 
array([[[8],
        [8],
        [8]]])

In [186]: _.shape
Out[186]: (1, 3, 1)
```